# How do I add a 'Restore Purchase' method to my In App Purchase

Tags: ios, iphone, object, in-app-purchase

I have coded In App Purchasing into my app and have made it work so that a user can make a purchase by pressing a button.

I now want to create a button for the user to be able to Restore Purchase. I am using a Shared Instance in 'UpgradeViewController' to retrieve methods from 'IAHelper.h' so I have shown both pieces of code incase it helps

How do I add a 'Restore Purchase' method to my In App Purchase?

**IAHelper.m**

```
#import "IAPHelper.h"

// Add to top of file
NSString *const IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification = @"IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification";

@implementation IAPHelper
{
    // 3
    SKProductsRequest * _productsRequest;
    // 4
    RequestProductsCompletionHandler _completionHandler;
    NSSet * _productIdentifiers;
    NSMutableSet * _purchasedProductIdentifiers;

        NSArray *_products;

}

- (id)initWithProductIdentifiers:(NSSet *)productIdentifiers {

    if ((self = [super init])) {

        // Store product identifiers
        _productIdentifiers = productIdentifiers;

        // Check for previously purchased products
        _purchasedProductIdentifiers = [NSMutableSet set];
        for (NSString * productIdentifier in _productIdentifiers) {
            BOOL productPurchased = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:productIdentifier];
            if (productPurchased) {
                [_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
                NSLog(@"Previously purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Not purchased: %@", productIdentifier);
            }
        }

        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHandler {

    // 1
    _completionHandler = [completionHandler copy];

    // 2
    _productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:_productIdentifiers];
    _productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [_productsRequest start];

}


#pragma mark - SKProductsRequestDelegate

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

    NSLog(@"Loaded list of products... %@", response.products);
    _productsRequest = nil;



    NSArray * skProducts = response.products;
    for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts) {
        NSLog(@"Found product: %@ %@ %0.2f",
              skProduct.productIdentifier,
              skProduct.localizedTitle,
              skProduct.price.floatValue);
    }

    _completionHandler(YES, skProducts);
    _completionHandler = nil;

}

- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"Failed to load list of products.");
    _productsRequest = nil;

    _completionHandler(NO, nil);
    _completionHandler = nil;

}


- (BOOL)productPurchased:(NSString *)productIdentifier {
    return [_purchasedProductIdentifiers containsObject:productIdentifier];
}

- (void)buyProduct:(SKProduct *)product {

    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);

    SKPayment * payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction * transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self completeTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [self failedTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                [self restoreTransaction:transaction];
            default:
                break;
        }
    };
}

- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");

    [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}

- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    NSLog(@"restoreTransaction...");

    [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}

- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {

    NSLog(@"failedTransaction...");
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        NSLog(@"Transaction error: %@", transaction.error.localizedDescription);
    }

    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
}

// Add new method
- (void)provideContentForProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier {

    [_purchasedProductIdentifiers addObject:productIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:productIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:productIdentifier userInfo:nil];

}

- (NSArray*)getProductArrray {

    return _products;

}

@end
```

**UpgradeViewController**

```
#import "UpgradeViewController.h"
#import "ECSlidingViewController.h"
#import "MenuViewController.h"



#import "RageIAPHelper.h"
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>

@interface UpgradeViewController ()

{
    NSMutableArray *_objects;

    NSArray *_products;

    NSNumberFormatter * _priceFormatter;


}


@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet JSAnimatedImagesView *animatedImagesView;
@property (assign, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *installFullAppButton;
@end

@implementation UpgradeViewController
@synthesize menuBtn, animatedImagesView = _animatedImagesView, scrolly, bannerView, labelPrice;


- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}



- (NSString *)publisherIdForAdSdkBannerView:(AdSdkBannerView *)banner {
    return @"e0616d4190bff65279ed5c20de1b5653";
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [RageIAPHelper sharedInstance];

    _products = nil;

    [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {
        if (success) {
            _products = products;

        }
    }];



    // Price New



    SKProduct * product = (SKProduct *) [_products objectAtIndex:0];


    ([[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] productPurchased:product.productIdentifier]);


        // Unlock your features code comes here

        UIButton *buyButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-1, 370, 320, 60)];
        UIImage *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"upgrade-new.png"];
        [buyButton setImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [buyButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0]];
        [buyButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [buyButton.titleLabel setShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1 alpha:1.0]];
        [buyButton.titleLabel setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, -1)];
        [buyButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buyButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        buyButton.tag = 0;
        [[self view] addSubview:buyButton];




    // Purchase Action End


    [super viewDidLoad];


    _priceFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [_priceFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
    [_priceFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    [_priceFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
    labelPrice.text = [_priceFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];




    self.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75f;
    self.view.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
    self.view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;


    if (![self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController isKindOfClass:[MenuViewController class]]) {
        self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController  = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Menu"];
    }


    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.slidingViewController.panGesture];

    self.menuBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    menuBtn.frame = CGRectMake(8, 30, 34, 24);
    [menuBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [menuBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(revealMenu:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    [self.view addSubview:self.menuBtn];


    myWebView.opaque = NO;
    myWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

}






- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)revealMenu:(id)sender
{
    [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewTo:ECRight];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.screenName = @"Upgrade";
}



#pragma mark - UI

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return (toInterfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}




- (void)buyButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    UIButton *buyButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    SKProduct *product = [_products objectAtIndex:buyButton.tag];

    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);
    [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product];

}








@end
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question...

Answer (score 1):

Apple will refuse your app if you do not have a button to do this, well they did me even though they recognised the app automatically checked in background.

Any way if you add this to your helper;

```
- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

And call like this from VC;

```
- (IBAction)restoreAction:(id)sender
{

    [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] restoreCompletedTransactions];

}
```

Comment: @Omar Also, in your didRecieveResponse in the IAPhelper you need to change the last few lines to check the completion handler to this or it crashes some times. if(_completionHandler){_completionHandler(YES, skProducts);}_completionHandler = nil;

Comment: Thank you, what does that line of code mean in didReceiveResponse?

Comment: It is three lines, it basically tests that the _completionHandler exists before it tries to set it (I think repeated pressing of purchases, re-store button can cause it to be at this point when it is not created).  It replaces the last two lines in that method.  I will show as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

After you have doen this;

```
- (void)restoreCompletedTransactions
{
     [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

And call like this from VC;

```
- (IBAction)restoreAction:(id)sender
{

    [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] restoreCompletedTransactions];

}
```

This methods needs to be changed to this;

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

    NSLog(@"Loaded list of products... %@", response.products);
    _productsRequest = nil;



    NSArray * skProducts = response.products;
    for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts) {
        NSLog(@"Found product: %@ %@ %0.2f",
              skProduct.productIdentifier,
              skProduct.localizedTitle,
              skProduct.price.floatValue);
    }

// Check is the Handler exists
if(_completionHandler)
{
    _completionHandler(YES, skProducts);
}
_completionHandler = nil;

}
```